# Can access a the key of an option tag element from the event handler function in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have a very specific and odd situation.

I have a large enough array of objects which stores all objects that need to be selected from a select box.

Sortav like this:

```
var optionsArray = [
   {
      name: option1,
      code: f2X
   },

   {
      name: option2,
      code: x21
   },
   ...
   {
      name: option100,
      code: Rga
   },

]
```

The point is, the code property is in no way related to the name of the options.

I currently put this in a select box, and upon selection of the option, I need to return the code of that option. Here is what the select box and even handler currently look like:

```
class SelectForm extends Component{
    onChange(e){
       console.log ("option selected", e.target.name);
       //I can access the name, but what I want to access is the the code
    }

    render(){
        var _this = this;

        return (
            <FormGroup controlId="myId">
                <FormControl componentClass="select" onChange={this.onChange}>
                    {
                      optionsArray.map(function(value, key) {
                      return <option key={key}>{value.name}</option>
                      })
                    }
                </FormControl>
                </FormGroup>
        );
    }
```

So basically in the event handler I want to access the code and not the name of the option I just selected.

I thought perhaps I can access the index of the array I selected from the key, and do something like this:

```
onChange(e){
   console.log ("selected option code", optionsArray[e.target.key].code);
}
```

But the key is undefined. Is there any way I can access the key of the selected option from the event? Or even better, is there a way I can just include the code in the option tag so I can later easily access it in the event handler?

Comment: Pass value as an attribute in `<option>` which will contain the code, and in function access it like `e.target.value`.

Comment: How so? As props perhaps? Because if this is the case, I have already tried to do so with key and value, and when I try to access it (for example e.target.key), it comes as undefined.

Comment: Ignore my previous comment, I didn't realize if I passed 'value' as a prop it would work.
Thanks (if you'd like to post that as an answer, I will mark it as answered my question)

Comment: Sure :) I just did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass `value` attribute in `option` which will contain the code value. So it would be something like

```
<FormControl componentClass="select" onChange={this.onChange}>
  {
     optionsArray.map(function(value, key) {
         return <option key={key} value={value.code}>{value.name}</option>
     })
  }
</FormControl>
```

and access it like `e.target.value` in your `onChange` function.

```
onChange(e){
   console.log ("option selected", e.target.value);
}
```